# Temporary Table with Person Names Replicated with 12 Times, with Each Row Inserted with a Month Number

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a temporary table that extracts the first name and last name of all profiles from the [Person] table in my SQL database. Then, I want to replicate each person 12 times in this new table and add a column called Month so that each of the 12 replicated rows is inserted with a digit (1-12) to represent a month of the year. Can you tell me how to create a SQL for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL [`UNION ALL`](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-union-all/) to create a list of each month repeated for each name.

Repeat the select query once for each month, change the month number for each one:

```
SELECT name, 1 `month` FROM EMPLOYEE 
  UNION ALL
SELECT name, 2 FROM EMPLOYEE 
  UNION ALL
SELECT name, 3 FROM EMPLOYEE 
  ORDER BY month, name
;
```

Given `EMPLOYEE` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Clark |
| 2 | Dave |
| 3 | Ava |

This outputs:

| name | month |
| --- | --- |
| Ava | 1 |
| Clark | 1 |
| Dave | 1 |
| Ava | 2 |
| Clark | 2 |
| Dave | 2 |
| Ava | 3 |
| Clark | 3 |
| Dave | 3 |

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  empId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  dept TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, 'Clark', 'Sales');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2, 'Dave', 'Accounting');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (3, 'Ava', 'Sales');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (4, 'Clark', 'Maintenance');

-- fetch 
SELECT name, 1 `month` FROM EMPLOYEE 
  UNION ALL
SELECT name, 2 FROM EMPLOYEE 
  UNION ALL
SELECT name, 3 FROM EMPLOYEE 
  ORDER BY month, name
;
```

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3ygcscr33

Note: `UNION ALL` is required in case names are the same for multiple people.